# far manager 3, conemu and clink - some integration issues

Tags: conemu, far-manager, clink

I use conemu as console and clink as shell and from conemu I launch far managaer using

```
far .
```

and this opens far manager on the current directory.

After exiting far manager and returning on conemu I would like to be in the path I was in far manager but instead I got back to the original path where I run far manager before.

Another issue: I would like that when I turn off the panels (ctrl-o) to be able to use clink (tab) completion. it's this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Just use Far Manager instead of cmd+clink. I see no sense in switching.

Comment: I like to have conemu with clink and when I need launch far manager, why you see this as no sense? I find the clink completition when I need to run some commands better that the one in far

Comment: Far Manager has integrated prompt which is much more handy than cmd even with clink.

Comment: Ok, I will try it better, but as my second question, at least can I setup it to use tab for autocompletition when panels are off?